# Вызов события при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery

Как можно сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Построен документ(DOM) и загружены все скрипты:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* */ });
```

Весь контент загружен:

```
$(window).load(function(){ /* */ });
```